# Cannot initialize LPUART1 in STM32CubeIDE on b-l072z-lrwan1?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart

I was having a problem about initializing the LPUART1 on b-l072z-lrwan1 using the built-in CubeMX code generation in STM32CubeIDE.

The problem was when I started debugging, the code seemed to run fine until the execution reached MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(); The debugger kept prompting

> Target is not responding, retrying... 
>   Error! Failed to read target status

and then the debugger shut down.

My question is how to properly initialize the LPUART1? Does it require any extra work to do in order to use this peripheral?

--

Anyway here's my LPUART1 peripheral configuration

```
static void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 1 */
  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_Init 2 */

}
```

The MspInit Function

```
void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(huart->Instance==LPUART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**LPUART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA14     ------> LPUART1_TX
    PA13     ------> LPUART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_LPUART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(huart->Instance==USART2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART2_TX
    PA3     ------> USART2_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = STLINK_RX_Pin|STLINK_TX_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* USART2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 1 */
  }
```

}

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by disabling the debugger? I've tried doing that by just pressing the stop button as well as disabling the software debugging but I still can't seem to get the LPUART1 working. I have the exact same init code as you do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *edit: Sorry, misclicked. At the time I was confusing because I was trying to use LPUART1 and debugger at the same time. The thing is, as Justme said, the LPUART1 and debugger use the same pins. When the LPUART1 is initialized, you can no longer use the debugger anymore but your program should be working fine after flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pins PA13 and PA14 you are trying to use for LPUART are already in use as the SWD/JTAG pins for debugging, so the debugging stops immediately when you change the pin configuration. Use another set of pins for serial comms or stop using the debugger.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried disabling debugger and the Serial port worked like a charm.